# Successfully connect to DB2 using PHP NOT using ODBC?

Tags: php, db2

Need to know if 1) anyone successfully made a connection and 2)queried a remote DB2 server using PHP, and 3) if so how?

I installed the PECL extension for db2

`[db2]
extension=ibm_db2.so`

but can't figure out how to use it. All the examples I find use ODBC style dsn, I don't want to use ODBC.

UPDATE: According to documentation here (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247218.html) it is nominally possible to use the ibm_db2 driver (sans ODBC) but the methodology described therein is either incomplete or outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Using PHP you only have one option: ODBC.

Here are step by step instructions for how to connect to DB2 for i (on the IBM i) on Ubuntu:

Download the free iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm file from IBM (you'll have to create a free account to get it)

Convert the RPM file to something Ubuntu understands: `sudo alien iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm`

Install the resulting .deb: `sudo dpkg -i iseriesaccess_6.1.0-2.2_i386.deb`

Copy the installed iSeries libraries to where Ubuntu expects them: `sudo cp /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/* /usr/lib`

Edit the /etc/odbc.ini file to contain:

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = IP_ADDRESS
UserID                  = USERNAME
Password                = PASSWORD
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
```

Edit the /etc/odbcinst.ini file to contain:

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

And then to create the connection with PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$server;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $username, $password);
```

Comment: You should probably indicate that this answer is applicable to DB2 i (AS/400) but not for other DB2 servers, no?

Comment: Very good point @mustaccio - thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my post to reflect my instructions are specific to DB2 for i rather than DB2 for LUW.

Comment: Sorry to dig out this old thread. But I stumbled on some garbage on my UTF8 data while working with unixODBC and iSeries DB2. You should add another line to your odbc.ini: DEBUG = 65536 - see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014094907#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014210307

Answer (score 1):

For DB2 LUW you'll need to install, at the minimum, the appropriate version of the DB2 Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI [from here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053). It supplies the required libraries used by the PHP module.

Comment: That is done as part as satisfying the requirements for compiling the PECL extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pecl ibm_db2 extension. It uses  DB2 Call Level Interface (DB2 CLI), so you must have IBM db2 CLI installed in your system.

This is the PHP DOC page:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.ibm-db2.php