# DB2 connection failure: Reason Code "0x124C" ("0209")

Tags: linux, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm new to DB2 so there's a decent chance I'm making a basic mistake here.

- Server is an as/400 running DB2.
- Client os: Linux (CentOS 7.3)
- Client s/w 1: IBM Data Server Driver Linux_x64 v11.1
- Client s/w 2: IBM i Access Client Solutions - Linux AP LCD8 2012 04

I've tried using Perl's DBD::DB2 module:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:DB2:DATABASE=$dbname; HOSTNAME=$host; PORT=$port; CONNTYPE=2", $user, $pass) || die "DB2 connection failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

And that results in:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30020N  Execution of the command or SQL statement failed because of a syntax error in the communication data stream that will affect the successful execution of subsequent commands and SQL statements:  Reason Code "0x124C"("0209")"".  SQLSTATE=58009
```

I've also tried with `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[testdm]
Description = Test db2
Driver      = /usr/local/dsdriver/lib/libdb2o.so
Trace       = Yes
TraceFile   = /var/tmp/rotate7/db2_odbc.log
Database    = S102YGCM.CHICAGO.LOCAL
System      = 10.0.0.2
UserName    = xxxxxxxx
Password    = xxxxxxxx
Port        = 446
```

And running `isql -v testdm` results in the similar:

```
[08001][unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30020N  Execution of the command or SQL statement failed because of a syntax error in the communication data stream that will affect the successful execution of subsequent commands and SQL statements:  Reason Code "0x124C"("0209")"".  SQLSTATE=58009
```

[This page at IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30020n.html) says that 124C means "The DRDA data stream for the request contains a syntax error."  But I don't know how to troubleshoot that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: IBM i does not "speak" the ODBC/CLI protocol, that's what the error message tells you. If you insist on using the ODBC driver you'll need to setup DB2 Connect as a gateway.

Comment: @mustaccio I'm open to using any protocol that works.  Anything that lets me run a SELECT statement would be an improvement over what I have now.

Comment: I don't know about Perl, but from PHP you need to use the IBM i Access ODBC driver to access DB2 for i without DB2 Connect. You obviously would have to get the Linux version of the drivers. Look here http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux.html

Comment: This question is about DB2 and PHP, but the top answer talks about how to get the correct driver. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17997669/2296441

Comment: @jmarkmurphy that PHP question did help me get odbc.ini fixed so that my isql command can now connect.  My Perl code doesn't read odbc.ini so it's still broken, but maybe I can change it to use ODBC.

Comment: ODBC is the only way to go if you don't have DB2 Connect.

Comment: If you installed iACS - Linux AP, can you post relevant lines from /etc/odbcinst.ini?